# Catch ALL quit events with NSAppleEventManager

Tags: macos, events

When my Mac OS app quits I want it to ask the user "Are you sure you want to quit [Yes] [No]".

I have tried this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    // Install a custom quit event handler
    NSAppleEventManager* appleEventManager = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
    [appleEventManager setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(handleQuitEvent:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kCoreEventClass andEventID:kAEQuitApplication];
}

// Handler for the quit apple event
- (void)handleQuitEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)replyEvent {
    // Insert YES/NO-dialog here
    // if(blahahaha..
    //[NSApp terminate:self];
}
```

But it only catch the quit that comes when right-clicking on my app on the dock and then choosing "Quit". If I press Cmd-Q or choose Quit from the app menu my handler is not invoked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all these cases involve Apple Events.  Instead, handle the app delegate method `-applicationShouldTerminate:`.